# How to test ag-grid with protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests, ag-grid

In my app, I use ag-grid to display the data. I am unsure on how I can select a field within the grid so that I can test if it is there or not. Many of the examples I have found have not been much help. If anybody could guide me in the right direction, that would be great!:) Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div style="height: 90%; text-align: left">
<ag-grid-angular enableColResize groupHeaders style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  class="ag-theme-blue" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]= "columnDefs" [enableSorting]="true"
  [animateRows]="true" [rowSelection]="rowSelection">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

And here is an example of how I create my data in my component class. I have figure I must select the array where I am outputting mt data but I cannot seem to figure out how to select the array. The closest I can get to selecting the fields is if I call the class ag-theme-blue. But that is not much help,as it only selects a specific user, there is no flexibility. Thank you!

```
 columnDefs = [

        { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'FirstName' },

    ];
```

EDIT: Okay, so I made some progress! It is not a solution but is a step in the right direction :). This line of code, selects the first column in the ag-grid.

```
return element(by.css('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]'))
```

This line here, allows me to select a specific index.

```
 return element.all(by.css('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]')).get(2);
```

This line here allows me to select the row with the given data. For example, here I am looking for a row that contains the name "TestName". Now I can test if a new field is added by checking if the field containing TestName is being displayed. To make this test even better, I can assign my test to add a name that is very distinct to ensure that it does not already exist in the database.

```
return element.all(by.cssContainingText('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]', 'TestName'))
```

This image on this site is what my grid looks like.

http://www.adaptabletools.com/ag_Grid_implementation_available.html

EDIT 2: Updated spec with function:

```
  it('should select name field', () => {




  findRow(page.rows, "TestName").then(row => {

    row.getText().then(rowText => {
      expect(rowText).toContain('TestName')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish? Does using `ag-theme-blue` only select the first user in the grid? Are you trying to verify that all users exist or that a specific user exists? Perhaps a screenshot of the page and an explanation of exactly what you want to verify would be helpful.

Comment: Sure thing. My apologies if I was not descriptive enough. I will add the new details above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a good handle on what you are trying to do now.

You can get a list of all the rows in the grid by using

`let rows = element.all(by.css('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]'));`

Then from here you can find a row that contains the data you are looking for by using `.filter()`. Probably best to create a generic function that allows you to pass in the rows and the string you are looking for and then return the element once you've found it.

```
findRow(elements, matcher) {
  const relevantRow = elements.filter(element => {
    return element.getText().then(text => {
      return text.includes(matcher);
    });
  })
  .first()

  return relevantRow;
}
```

You can call it from your tests: `const row = findRow(rows, 'Some Text')` and then once you have the row you are looking for you can do whatever you need with it from there.

EDIT:
Here is an example that is more clear

```
// in your page object
public rows = element.all(by.css('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]'));

// in some helper class
function findRow(rows, matcher) {
  return elements.filter(element => {
    return element.getText().then(text => {
      return text.includes(matcher);
    });
  })
  .first()
}

//in your test
helper.findRow(somePage.rows, 'Some Text').then(row => {
  row.getText().then(rowText => {
    expect(rowText).toContain('Some Text');
  });
});
```

If you are using async/await it would be like this

```
function async findRow(rows, matcher) {
  const relevantRow = await rows.filter(row => {
    return row.getText().then(text => {
      return text.includes(matcher);
    });
  }).first();

  return relevantRow;
}

//in spec
const row = await helper.findRow(somePage.rows, 'Some Text');
expect(await row.getText()).toContain('Some Text');
```

Comment: Hello. I tried to emulate your function but I recive the follow error when running my test: "-Failed: elements.filter is not a function" I use the exact model you presented. In my test, I call the function like this: `await page.row.click()`. In my object class I create the row variable like so: `row = findRow('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]', 'Desired value'`. Any input would be great! Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, it should be `element.all`. Didn't realize I made a mistake in my answer. I've updated with the correct info.

Comment: Thank you. Where do you recommend I create the rows variable, in the object class? Because I am having trouble passing rows into my test class `findRows(rows, 'test')`, as it cannot be found. I create the rows varibale in my object class like so: ` rows = element.all(by.css('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]')). I also created a separate class for the findRows function, and I export it so that I can import it to my test class. Thank you.
`

Comment: Yeah, I'll update my answer with an example that is more clear.

Comment: Thank you very much! The only issue is that protractor does not recognize rows. I get the following error when preforming my test: `- NoSuchElementError: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, div.ag-body-container > [role="row"])` So for some reason, protractor is not accessing the rows element on the page. I edited my question above to display my spec.

Comment: That error means it didn't find a match in the list of rows. Try logging the text in `findRow` to the console to see what it's actually finding. Then you can compare with what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but am unsure of how to keep chrome open, even when the test fails. I believe you cannot log angular to the shell  from a test :/

Comment: Yeah, you can just use `console.log(text)` and it should show up in your shell. You don't need to keep the browser open.

Comment: Alright, so it was a weird problem... I could not log anything which led me to belive that protractor not waiting to preform to test, even with the async and await aspects. So for testing purposes I threw in a browser.sleep and protractor was not even executing that line, protractor just went straight to the function and crashed. So I took out page.navigateTo() as I did not need it (my mistake) and now it is working fine. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Would you happen to know why the function does not get the data at the end of the test? I am testing an edit function. I change the the first name then runs the function after I change the name. My test fails saying: expected row toContain intialName not editedName. This may not be appropriate to this specific question so my apologies

Answer (score 0):

Well not perfect, this seemed to do the trick:

```
return element.all(by.cssContainingText('div.ag-body-container > [role="row"]', 'TestName'))
```

Now I just need to figure out how to retrieve the data from the field.