# Find a value in a grid with protractor

Tags: protractor, ag-grid

I use the FindRow function that I found here : [How to test ag-grid with protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843128/how-to-test-ag-grid-with-protractor)

but unfortunately when I execute the function, it returns me a known error message:

```
Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .ag-body-container > .ag-row)
```

this my test code :

```
it('My Test', async function() {
      const rows = element.all(by.css('.ag-body-container > .ag-row'));
      const row = await findRow(rows, 'Some Text');
      expect(await row.getText()).toContain('Some Text');
});
```

this my function :

```
async function findRow(rows, matcher) {
    const relevantRow = await rows.filter(row => {
      return row.getText().then(text => {
        return text.includes(matcher);
      });
    }).first();

    return relevantRow;
  }
```

I have already tried the following solution but without success :

```
 var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(rows), 500);
```

I know that this error message often comes up in e2e tests, but I can't find a solution.

if there is another solution that would allow me to find a value in a grid I am also interested

Comment: Which version of ag-grid are you using?

Comment: @thirtydot old Version Ag-grid: 3.3